# SQLITE_ERROR SQL error or missing database (near "SCHEMA": syntax error)

Tags: sql, sqlite, sbt

I am trying to run this script on SQLite DB (in my SBT project) but I got this error?

```
[2018-01-25 22:18:58] [1] [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing 
     database (near "SCHEMA": syntax error)
```

May you know how can I solve it?

```
# Air SCHEMA

# --- !Ups

CREATE TABLE products (
  id          BIGSERIAL    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  title       VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
  price       BIGINT(2500) NOT NULL
);


CREATE INDEX products._idx
  ON products (id);

# --- !Downs

DROP TABLE products;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use SQL comments:

```
-- Air SCHEMA
```

instead of Python comments:

```
# Air SCHEMA
```

Comment: Sure! But in 7 mins! :p

Comment: 7 mins have passed! :P